# Trino S3 partitions folder structure

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, trino

I do not understand what paths Trino needs in order to create table from existing files. I use S3 + Hive metastore.

My JSON file:

```json
{"a":1,"b":2,"snapshot":"partitionA"}
```

Create table command:

```sql
create table trino.partitioned_jsons (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, snapshot varchar) with (external_location = 's3a://bucket/test/partitioned_jsons/*', format='JSON', partitioned_by = ARRAY['snapshot']
```

What I have tried:

1. Store JSON file in `s3://bucket/test/partitioned_jsons/partitionA/file.json`
2. Store JSON file in `s3://bucket/test/partitioned_jsons/snapshot=partitionA/file.json`
3. Store JSON file in `s3://bucket/test/partitioned_jsons/snapshot/partitionA.json`

But all returns just an empty table.